# Laravel send mail using queue() not working on server

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-mail

I have trying to send mail using Laravel queue job, and my site on hostmonster web server but it is not sending mail when I fire `php artisan queue:work`, It clears Job table but not mail received to my email address.

**Here is my code to queue and send mail function:**

```
    //It is working
    $to = '****@g***l.com';
    \Mail::to($to)->send(new ContactUsMail($contactUsId));

    //It is not working: on same host email working not work with hotmail - gmail - other
    $to = '****@g***l.com';
    \Mail::to($to)->queue(new ContactUsMail($contactUsId));
```

The mail send working fine with 2 case:

1. If I send mail using `send()` method (bypass/ignore queue)
2. also using `queue()` send to same hosting email (like `info@myhost.com`)

But now if I use `xyz@yahoo.com`/`xyz@gmail.com` then in such case queue not working - job table also delete entry as mail sent but bingo..!! where mail send I don't know.

Also cron mail same problem as queue simple `mail()` function working there not `Mail::send()` work there..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many tries I have found solution with my server that is below setting working fine :

`.env` file setup `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail`.

`config/mail.php` file `'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t'` replace `-bs` with `-t`.

Comment: I had the same problem with Laravel hosted on Hostgator and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to execute the [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker) `php artisan queue:work`.
2. change `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` to `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis` or `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`

Comment: I already have run command `php artisan queue:work` and change for queue driver also made there `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`, but then also not working.

Comment: Did you check the failed table ?

Comment: There I only found `jobs` table that i was added to queue manage, no such `failed` table found there. The mail send working fine in 2 case: 1. If I send mail using send() method (bypass/ignore queue) 2. also using queue send to same hosting email (like info@myhost.com); if i use xyz@yahoo.com/xyz@gmail.com then in such case queue not working - job table also delete entry as mail sent but bingo..!! where mail send I don't know.

Comment: you can use `php artisan queue:failed-table`  and `php artisan migrate` to generate a failed table
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: There with cron `Mail::send()` also not working there is trying to setup `phpmailer` and it working fine but Laravel mail no sent..!

Comment: I have added `failed-table` there is nothing data or record found after queue:work, just clean job table.

Comment: Thanks, my issues was I had the default driver as "sync" in the .env +1!